# R's ggplot2: jitter does not respect height=0

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does

```
library(ggplot2)
plotdata <- data.frame(value=as.numeric(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,1)))
plotdata$feature <- "Colour1"
ggplot(plotdata, aes(feature,value)) +
  geom_jitter(height=0) +
  facet_wrap(~feature)
```

result in

[image]

even though I have `height=0` - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I could not reproduce your error (wth ggplot2_2.0.0), running your example code gives me a plot with horizontal jitter, but all points on the lines of 1, 2 and 3

Comment: This works for me and I am using version `ggplot2_2.0.0` of `ggplot2`. What version of `ggplot2` are you using ?  This could be a bug in the version you are using.

Comment: @steveb: I'm using 1.0.1 - I'm going to try to update.

Comment: Updating worked. If s.o. posts an answer'll except it.

Comment: @Make42 This answer looks a bit like a group effort.

Comment: @steveb: :-D Seems to be. Acctually I was suggesting that you guys put the answer there and I accept it, but now Heroka already started editing :-D.

Answer (score 0):

Update ggplot2 to ggplot2.2.0.0 or higher - this is a bug.